# How to get form value from span

Tags: php, html, daterangepicker

I am working on [Date-Range-Picker](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker). It inserts date between spans.

Now my question is how can I get the inserted values in spans using form POST or GET methods in PHP.

I have tried using name field in the span, but its not working

My html is :

```
<form method="POST" action="">

<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px;">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar icon-large"></i>
                                <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
                            </div>

</form>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You need form elements to be able to use `$_POST` or `$_GET`, you can't use a `span`.

Comment: Of course you can. Ajax does not need a form

Comment: @putvande Please check my html. I get date value between span tags, now how can I get it in backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this would be to use input text boxes that are hidden to post values.
You can populate the input text boxes every time the span is changed with jQuery.